# PHP How to use SELECT & POST

Tags: php, html, select, post

```
<form action="seach_simple.php" method="POST" >
      <h4>
      <table width="800" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
            <th scope="col">Отношение</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:160px;">Величина</th>
          </tr>

          <tr><p><td><i>Номер чертежа</i></td> 

            <td>
                 <select id="ratio_NC" name="ratio_NC">
                        <option value="=" selected="selected">=</option>
                        <option value="!=">!=</option> 
                        <option value="<">&lt;</option>
                        <option value=">">&gt;</option>
                        <option value="<=">&lt;=</option>
                        <option value=">=">&gt;=</option>
                     </select>
                     <td><input type="text" name="NC"  /></td>
                 </p>
                  </tr></td>
      </table></h4>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Generate SQL" /></p>
    </form>
```

And PHP

```
$code_NC = $_POST['NC'];
$ratio_NC = $_POST['ratio_NC'];
echo "$code_NC";
echo "$ratio_NC";
```

The problem is that I get the value from the "INPUT" and nothing from the "SELECT", don't know what to do. 
Will be glad for help.

Comment: I have tested the code in my pc,it is working well

Answer (score 1):

You need to HTML encode the values in the value fields as well.

`>` becomes `&gt;`, `<` becomes `&lt;`

Comment: @user It's invalid HTML, you should do it in any case. (@Kabir probably has the solution though)

Comment: Now im just change the id="ratio_NC" for another and done, its work. thank

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$ratio_NC = htmlentities($_POST['ratio_NC']);
```

Answer (score 0):

User htmlentities like

```
$ratio_NC = htmlentities($_POST['ratio_NC']);
```

because I think it is problem with the html entities that you are using are contraversy while posting and I think its not the utf-8 data like

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for me. I have tested it on Mozilla FireFox
Here is my code I tried. Please try this

```
<?php
$code_NC = $_POST['NC'];
$ratio_NC = $_POST['ratio_NC'];
echo $code_NC;
echo $ratio_NC;
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="" method="POST" >
      <h4>
      <table width="800" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
            <th scope="col">Отношение</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:160px;">Величина</th>
          </tr>

          <tr><p><td><i>Номер чертежа</i></td> 

            <td>
                 <select id="ratio_NC" name="ratio_NC">
                        <option value="=" selected="selected">=</option>
                        <option value="!=">!=</option> 
                        <option value="<">&lt;</option>
                        <option value=">">&gt;</option>
                        <option value="<=">&lt;=</option>
                        <option value=">=">&gt;=</option>
                     </select>
                     </td>
                     <td><input type="text" name="NC"  /></td>
                 </p>
                  </tr>
      </table></h4>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Generate SQL" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```